# Lowest level database support for a free website

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am looking to create a small personal web site using Azure web sites free tier. As part of the project I would add minimal database support. This is a hobby project so I want to stay within the constraints of the free web sites.

Here are some of the options I am considering:

- SqlLite
- RavenDb (RavenDB Asp.Net Hosted or Embedded)
- CouchDb (don't think this will work but I have not investigated enough)
- .sdf file

Short of using XML files, is there a good database option for the free web site tier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an Azure website you get a 20 Megabyte SQL Server database for free.  Granted, that is not much, but if you are considering SqlLite, perhaps that is enough.

The small print from [their website](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/).

> 1. Free and Shared (Preview) tiers include 60 minutes and 240 minutes
>      of CPU capacity per day, respectively.
> 2. These quotas are per
>      sub-region unless noted otherwise.
> 3. One 20MB Azure SQL Database and
>      one 20MB MySQL database are available at the subscription level for
>      the first twelve months of use; standard rates apply thereafter.

Comment: And... both of these options are "as-a-service": No database install needed.

Comment: I think SqlLite is path I'll take, mostly so I don't have to monitor when 12 months are up with the SQL Azure option.

Comment: When you consider that it only costs about a $0.01 a day to run a database that small.. its crazy convenient and cheap.  Best of luck tho!

Comment: @paqogomez can you give me a link to that pricing... it's about $0.16 a day, and reducing to $0.12 soon... still cheap but not $0.01

Comment: @Martin, not sure where you are seeing that price.  [FTA](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/): `Web Sites Shared (Preview): The price for the Shared tier during preview is $0.013 per hour (~$10/month). This price reflects a 33% preview discount.`

Comment: @paqogomez, the question is about databases, i can't see any database pricing around the value stated.  The 20mb database only lasts for the first 12 months.